# Which is the best development tool for CBT (computer based training) / LMS (learning management system)

Tags: flash, apache-flex

The CBT involves user interaction, like quizes, quiz progress, licensing etc.

Should I go with flex, or should I go with flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is best suited for making movies and animations .. In Flex you can't make (time-line) movies and animations at all. But both Flex and Flash allow you to develop applications ..

**Flex:**

Pros:

•good for RIA development
•provides many user-input options out of the box
•the MXML is easier for non-programmers
•You can quickly combine components to create small applications
•components can provide an advantage in large-scale projects because of their modular nature.
•can be developed using linux
•has a nice component lifecycle for validation, etc.

Cons:

•increases the size of your .swf
•Customizing the look of components can take a lot longer than anticipated, depending on the visual style you're looking for
•when you find out you need a custom component that doesn't exist, you might need to go back to Flash to do the real programming work and packaging of the component
•The "flexibility" of Flex means you will be reading a lot of documentation
•Bugs in the Flex framework
•You eventually will need to compromise with the architecture of the Flex framework

**Flash**

Pros:

•good for making movies/animations
•Timeline can be easier for designers/animators to conceptualize
•when working from scratch, provides a great deal of control.
•easier for someone with a programming background
•You can program whatever you like; no compromises with existing frameworks

Cons:

•only provides basic user input (text box) out of the box.
•timeline can be daunting for programmers (although you can quite safely ignore it)
•Development of certain types of applications will be slower than with Flex
•can't be developed using linux
•user input validation must all be handled in the code. No built-in validation.

Comment: when you said certain type of applications .. could you be more elaborate?

Comment: :) There is no limitation on using Adobe Flash and Adobe Photoshop .. It all depends on how much expert you are on those topics .. So by "application" I mean everything .. (includes from simple presentation to Hi quality online Gaming ..)